# what does holographic principle from string theory say about the possibilities of wormhole travel?

Tags: string-theory, black-holes, quantum-gravity, holographic-principle, wormholes

Is travel through stable macroscopic wormholes between remote points of spacetime going to be possible in a definitive theory of gravity, be it string theory or something beyond it?

Physicists level of understanding about the holographic principle and AdS/CFT correspondence has improved significantly and continues to evolve, as it is suggested by the current ongoing debate regarding black hole firewalls.

I understand that the semiclassical picture of wormholes cannot survive because string theory demands that the required positive energy conditions are satisfied, so nontrivial classical topologies are censored from geodesically-complete world lines, just like naked singularities. But i cannot help but wonder (and hence my reason to do this question) if all the thorny subject about information being conserved by unitarity, while at the same time, holography implying there is a connection between all the boundaries of the bulk spacetime (understanding as such the union of the cosmological horizon and all the black holes in its interior), *could allow room for solutions where the infalling information in black holes survives by coming out, scrambled or otherwise, out of some other distant event horizon* (behaving at times as a white hole, at others like a black hole)

Comment: As this stands, it is incoherent and just a collection of random buzzwords. Can you please be more explicit and clear / provide some background information?

Comment: The question looks pretty clear to me. The last part sounds like some speculative suggestion regarding far-away horizons becoming connected as a single entity in order to facilitate travel. He wants to know if that is possible or allowed by the theory. My guess is that is not possible, but the string theorists should answer this

Comment: Here's one relevant reference: http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0705.2768

Comment: thanks @MattReece, at page 14, what is the paradox they suggest arises between such wormholes and AdS/CFT?

Comment: Nah @dimension10 and Chris Gerig, to me it seems not that bad ;-), maybe because I have read [this](http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/06/finding-and-abandoning-incorrect.html) TRF article which seems to be related to the issues asked about here.

Answer (score 2):

*Is travel through stable macroscopic wormholes between remote points of spacetime going to be possible in a definitive theory of gravity, be it string theory or something beyond it?*

Extremely unlikely, and that's being generous.  The non-locality of quantum gravity is going to be irrelevant at macroscopic scales.  Any situation involving humans is going to be very well described by general relativity, so you can't sidestep the classical instability of wormholes by appealing to quantum fairie dust.

It is perhaps theoretically possible that microscopic wormholes would allow non-local transmission of information, but the energy budget required for that sort of thing involves numbers so mind-boggling that they're usually not seen outside of combinatorics.  Imagine destroying a solar system to send a single bit, and you're lowballing it.

Comment: "so you can't sidestep the classical instability of wormholes by appealing to quantum fairie dust"
we already sidestep a lot of classically expected results thanks to 'quantum fairie dust'. Most significant case is quantum superconductivity, which is clearly a macroscopic effect, and entirely due to 'quantum fairie dust'